# PL/SQL procedure error object TESTDB.GETNAME is invalid

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working on store procedure.I write a procedure in oracle 11g and calling the procedure in my java application.The procedure is returning a string.Here is my procedure

```
create or replace procedure GETNAME
(
CName out varchar2
)
is
BEGIN
select name into CName from customer where id=1;
END;
/
```

When i call the procedure in java it is giving the exception. The exception is given below

```
object TESTDB.GETNAME is invalid
```

My java code is give below

```
String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe";
    String USERNAME = "system";
    String PASSWORD = "metis";

    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        con.setAutoCommit(true);

        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call TESTDB.GETNAME(?)}");

        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cs.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(cs.getString(1));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("not connected");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Tell me what is the mistake i am doing here. I'll be thankful.... :)

Comment: It means your procedure has compilation errors, try to recompile the proceedure in the database and then try to call it. Recompilation can be done like this "ALTER PROCEDURE TESTDB.GETNAME COMPILE"; If the recompilation fails please paste the exception --> "ORA-XXXXX"

Comment: @ivanzg no compilation error in database error in java and this is the error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:

Comment: What does `select * from all_objects where status='INVALID' and object_type like 'PROC%'; ` gives when run on your database?

Comment: The exception is propagated to java via your calling of the stored procedure. Try to access the database and recompile the procedure.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use the `SYSTEM` account for "normal" work. Do ***NOT*** create any objects (tables, views, procedures, functions) using the `SYSTEM` account. Do ***NOT*** use the `SYSTEM` account for anything else than real DBA work (startup, shutdown, creating users)